Differences between Pgadmin4 Container or Extension
On a local development environment I want to spin up a postgres database. I'd like to use a docker to I don't retain any footprint for postgres when the development is complete.
What are the differences between using the pgadmin4 docker extension and the dpage/pgadmin4 docker image?
Which is a preferable route for a temporary project?
